# Точки разрыва на графике

Tags: delphi, диаграммы, график, функции

Нужно построить график y=log7(|x|)
Соответственно, есть точка разрыва при x=0. При этом Делфи (как и Эксель) в таком случае вместо нуля принимает x равным какому-то очень маленькому числу, выраженному через экспоненту. Из-за этого при x=0, y=-17.532
Пытаюсь построить график и сделать точки разрыва, для этого использую 2 series. Но проблема в том, что при определенных x график строится нормально, а при других либо "недостраивается", либо наоборот строит лишнюю линию, смотря как в коде написать.
Пишу например вот так и в итоге получается непонятно что:

```
begin
Series1.Clear;
series2.Clear;
StringGrid1.Cells[0,0]:='X';
StringGrid1.Cells[1,0]:='Y';
xn:=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
xk:=StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
dx:=StrToFloat(Edit4.Text);
x:=xn;
i:=0;
repeat
y:=LogN(7,ABS(x));
i:=i+1;
StringGrid1.Cells[0,i]:= FormatFloat('0.000',x);
StringGrid1.Cells[1,i]:= FormatFloat('0.000',y);
StringGrid1.RowCount:=i;
if (x<0) then
series1.AddXY(x,y);
if (x>(abs(dx))) then
series2.AddXY(x,y);
x:=x+dx;
until x>xk+dx;
Chart1.visible:=true;
StringGrid1.visible:=true;
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. В районе точки разрыва уменьшаем dx (чем больше модуль первой производной, тем меньше должно быть приращение).
2. Контролируем значение y:

   ```
   if y < -10 then y := -10;
   ```

   или

   ```
   if y < -10 then continue;
   ```

   Только не забываем про приращение `x`.
3. Меняем `if(x > (abs(dx))) then` на `if(x > 0) then`